# Matlab - Trapezoidal membership function

Tags: matlab, set, membership, fuzzy-logic

I have used the `trapezoidal membership function` through `matlab` as shown [here](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/fuzzy/trapmf.html).

I have written the following in matlab:

```
>> x=1:5;
>> y=trapmf(x,[1 3 4 5]);
```

And, for `y`, I got the following results:

```
>> y

y =

         0    0.5000    1.0000    1.0000         0
```

My questions are as follows:

How do we read the vector `y` shown above? Does it show the degrees of memberships for the elements in the set `x`?

For example, can we say the following?

- The degree of membership of `1` in the set `x` is `0`
- The degree of membership of `2` in the set `x` is `0.5000`
  .
  .
  .etc

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.. you are rite... That is how u read y..
I can't give any references for this but you can generally look at these wiki articles about fuzzy sets...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membership_function_(mathematics)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_set